# composer.lock is killing my push to heroku?

Tags: git, bash, heroku

[image]

I simply added it to my `.gitignore` b.c. I don't need it in my repo and all of the sudden Heroku would not accept my push.

Comment: ... and I can push to github just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku runs some checks, based on the selected repo language / technology, when you push code into it with Git pre-receive hooks. You are trying to run PHP app. One of the checks for PHP repos enforces that the repo [must include `composer.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation). Even if you don't need it you must commit empty JSON:

> The Heroku PHP Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a file named `composer.json` in the root directory. Even if an application has no Composer dependencies, it **must include** at least an empty (`{}`) `composer.json` in order to be recognized as a PHP application.

And you have some dependencies in it, `composer.lock` is required:

> If `composer.json` specifies dependencies of any kind in its require section, the corresponding `composer.lock` that gets generated by running `composer update` **must** also be committed to the repository

And you can push your code to Github because it doesn't have such a hook.

Comment: Thanks, but I checked and composer.lock is in the heroku repo.  Plus i committed, and pushed the file, but it still gives me this error.  I think this is a bug.  I think it has something to do with git telling heroku to delete the file.  I did delete it once in my local repo, and this is when the problems began.